# Creating a Google BigQuery stored procedure through the REST API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a Google BigQuery stored procedure using the REST API. I tried all the methods of the REST Resource `routines`. However, it didn't help.

Has anyone ever created a BigQuery stored procedure through the REST API? If so, how?

Comment: Considering [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) is displayed as being in Beta, and that when I tried with the [`routines.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/routines/insert) method with `routineType` set to `PROCEDURE` it returned me a `501: Not Implemented: Unsupported routine type PROCEDURE`, I believe it's it's not ready for use yet.

Comment: You could use DDL instead and issue it as SQL/Query job. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure

Comment: Do you want to use REST API or BQ CLI?

Answer (score 1):

As Graham noted on his comment, just issue a SQL query like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE mydataset.AddDelta(INOUT x INT64, delta INT64)
BEGIN
  SET x = x + delta;
END;
```

Do this as any other query with the REST API.

Comment: thanks  everyone...Question is more - how do i call BQ stored proc form REST API - We want to schedule it through External Application. As Graham mentioned, we can call query - however, we also wants to try a stored proc as logic can't implement in a simple query.

Comment: For calling the stored procedure with REST, there is not yet an option under [routines section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/routines), so you can create a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible to create a PROCEDURE:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/datasets/mydataset/routines?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"routineReference":{"projectId":"my-project","datasetId":"mydataset","routineId":"test_routine"},"routineType":"PROCEDURE","definitionBody":"BEGIN SET y = y + delta;END;","arguments":[{"name":"y","dataType":{"typeKind":"INT64"},"mode":"INOUT"},{"name":"delta","dataType":{"typeKind":"INT64"}}]}' \
  --compressed
```

Once created you can call it;

```
DECLARE accumulator INT64 DEFAULT 0;
CALL help.test_routine2(accumulator, 3);
CALL help.test_routine2(accumulator, 6);
SELECT accumulator;

Row accumulator 
1   9
```

You can [Try the API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/routines/insert) where I tested the command above.

Answer (score 0):

*A few years later...*

This is the code i use for create routine in BigQuery via API (prototype).
NB: i don't find the `setDescription` method in the `RoutineInfo.Builder`...

```
public void createRoutine(String datasetName, String routineName, String parameters, String script) {
    RoutineId routineId = RoutineId.of(datasetName, routineName);

    RoutineInfo.Builder routineInfoBuilder = RoutineInfo.newBuilder(routineId)
            .setLanguage("SQL")
            .setRoutineType("PROCEDURE")
            .setBody(script);
    if(StringUtils.hasText(parameters)) {
        List<RoutineArgument> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> params = List.of(parameters.split(","));
        for (String param : params) {
            String[] ps = param.trim().split(" ");
            String paramName = ps[0];
            StandardSQLDataType dataType = convertType(ps[1]);
            RoutineArgument argument = RoutineArgument.newBuilder()
                    .setName(paramName)
                    .setDataType(dataType)
                    .build();
            arguments.add(argument);

        }
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(arguments)) {
            routineInfoBuilder.setArguments(arguments).build();
        }
    }
    RoutineInfo routineInfo = routineInfoBuilder.build();

    bigQuery.create(routineInfo);
    log.info("Routine created {}:{}", datasetName, routineName);
}

/*
Supported type : BOOL, INT64, FLOAT64, NUMERIC, STRING, BYTES, STRUCT, ARRAY, TIMESTAMP, DATE, TIME, DATETIME, GEOGRAPHY
 */
private StandardSQLDataType convertType(String type) {
    StandardSQLTypeName r = StandardSQLTypeName.valueOf(type);
    return StandardSQLDataType.newBuilder(r).build();
}
```